# How to add GMT from date string

Tags: java, jodatime

This is the date coming from db
2015-06-0403:34:38

I have parsed it like this

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime("2015-06-0403:34:38");
```

result : `2015-06-04T03:34:38.000+05:00`

Now I want this date to add the GMT automatically with +5 in this case 
so the date would be `2015-06-04 08:34:38`

I have tried to add the timezone like this

```
java.util.Calendar now = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();
DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone.getID());
DateTime dateTimez = dateTime.toDateTime(dtZone);
```

result  : 2015-06-04T03:34:38.000+05:00 (which is wrong)

I am using `JodaTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse a DateTime object, it returns the DateTime object in the Systems TimeZone. Hence your `dateTime` object is already in `GMT+5`.
In `dateTimez` you are just getting the same DateTime with same timezone. Hence it doesn't change.

**Fix:**

```
dateTime = dateTime.withZoneRetainFields(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone) // pass the Timezone of the DB
DateTime dateTimez = dateTime.toDateTime(dtZone);
```

Comment: The date coming from db is in utc

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances) about how to get timeDiff. Using this answers you can build a method to add or remove hour based on timezone wanted.